# "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" within cmd, but works in PyCharm

Tags: python, cmd, command-line

I'm using the code below to output an array of dicts into a csv file. In PyCharm, it creates a new file or updates an existing file with the same name.
When run from a .bat file, it works as above.
When I schedule the .bat file to be run within Windows Task Scheduler, it fails with:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test-25-Apr-2020.csv'

Things I've tried so far:

1. Updated the project folder Security Permissions so that every type
   of user has all the permissions set to "Allowed".
2. Confirmed that the file is not open at the time of it being written to.
3. Created a shortcut of the .bat and set that to Run As Administrator, and referenced it in the Task Scheduler.
4. Moved the project folder from
       D:\ to directly beneath C:\

.

```
import csv
import datetime

def downloadCSV(result, file):
    keys = result[0].keys()
    with open(file, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(result)

inputList = [
    {"test": "value1"},
    {"test": "value2"},
    {"test": "value3"},
    { "test": "value4"}
]

timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()
formattedTime = timeNow.strftime("%d") + "-" + timeNow.strftime("%b") + "-" + timeNow.strftime("%Y")
fileName = 'test-' + formattedTime + '.csv'

downloadCSV(inputList, fileName)
```

Comment: Are you running PyCharm as an administrator?

Comment: The problem lays in your TS settings. Which you don't post but have gone to some effort to duplicate in code.

Comment: @GaneshSatpute My PyCharm does not run as administrator. I was hoping the combination of #1 and #3 from my list above would take care of any permissions issues.

Comment: @Mark I don't know what TS settings are, could you elaborate please?

Comment: Task Scheduler settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two changes were made for it to work:

1. Per Mark's comment, I updated the Task Scheduler setting for this task to 'Run with the highest privileges' on the General tab. This fixed the error but the file was still not being created.
2. I specified a file creation path:  with open('C:/test/'+file, 'w', newline='') as output_file:
   This made the file be created!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue with Task Scheduler.  I tried / and \ and other options (run with highest privileges" but still had issues.  What worked for me was to cd into the directory withhin the bat file.

Previously, my .bat file was simply:

```
python "C:\path\to\some\directory\run.py"
```

I updated my .bat file to:

```
cd "C:\path\to\some\directory"
python run.py
```

Hopefully this helps others that run into this.